# Powershell "move-item : Cannot create a file when that file already exists." despite using -force

Tags: powershell

When running my code i get the following error
"move-item : Cannot create a file when that file already exists."

I've tried adding -force to the end of my Move-Item as suggested by other forums online but that doesn't work.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "\\NetworkLocation\FolderA\Backup\" 
$originalLocation = "\\NetworkLocation\FolderA\"
$filestoreName=Read-Host -Prompt "Folder to Restore" 
$Rename=Read-Host -Prompt "Rename file to?"
Rename-Item -Path "\\NetworkLocation\FolderA\Backup\$filestoreName" -NewName "$Rename"
$filestore = "\\NetworkLocation\FolderA\Backup\$Rename"
move-item -Path $filestore -Destination $originalLocation -Force
```

In this scenario we've previously backed up a folder and we're now trying to restore it by overwriting the file in the original location. However it's unable to do the move because the folder already exists

Comment: Perhaps `Remove-Item` needs to be used before `Move-Item`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Move-Item` cannot overwrite, that's it.
But it can rename at the same time as it moves!

have a bit of code:

```
$BaseDirectory = '\\NetworkLocation\FolderA'
Write-Verbose "BaseDirectoy: $BaseDirectory"


$OriginalFolder = Read-Host -Prompt 'Folder to Restore' 
Write-Verbose "OriginalFolder: $OriginalFolder"

$OldFolder = Join-Path -Path $BaseDirectory -ChildPath 'Backup' -AdditionalChildPath $OriginalFolder 
Write-Verbose "OldFolder: $OldFolder"

$NewName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Rename file to?' 
Write-Verbose "NewName: $NewName"

$TargetFolder = Join-Path -Path $BaseDirectory -ChildPath $NewName 
Write-Verbose "TargetFolder: $TargetFolder"

Remove-Item -Path $TargetFolder -Force 
Write-Verbose "$TargetFolder was removed"

Move-Item -Path $OldFolder -Destination $TargetFolder -Force
```